# Copy from server

Tags: system-installation

I need to install more than 10 in 1 day a distro. I think if I install it on a server or install on a cool disk , Then cp into new server it's better.

Do you have a solution?

Comment: Ten installations per day sounds… um, pretty effortless, even without any tricks? Had to do that to mixed bag of laptops last month the night before a workshop I was giving, and it was done in like 1.5 hr. If you want to actually handle this in a scalable manner, you learn how the automated installation methods of your specific Linux distro works, set that up and just boot into the installer on all 10 at once. There's no tricks there – just follow your distro's instructions for automated installations.

Comment: I need it for datacenter.

Comment: Won't you just boot images as VMs there?

Comment: No, we need to install bare OS.

Comment: So, then lean into your distro's method of automated network installation. Basically, you'd tell all your server's BMC to boot from network, offer a PXE installer, which uses your favourite distro's method of defining an installation; done. Also did that before, it's just been a while.